# Database, store relationships

Tags: database-schema

I'm currently making an application to let sportives meet other sportives in order to play together. The problem is about listing relationships in database. I found a working solution as follows.

```
--------   -----------------
| User |   | Relationships |
--------   -----------------
| id   |   |    id         |
--------   |    idUser1    |
           |    idUser2    |
           -----------------
```

However I feel like there is room for improvement, is there a better way to solve this situation ?

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't *need* `id` in Relationships, though it could be handy
2. Add check constraint so that user cannot have relationship with self
3. Add unique constraint (idUser1, idUser2) so don't duplicate relationships
4. You are using foreign key yes?
5. Got indexes?
6. Consider adding reflexive relationships, ie when add relationship (user1, user2) you would also add (user2, user1) . This might make access control easier and let's someone "defriend" you without you defriending them.
7. Will there only ever be one type of relationship?